# imageJ plugin argument

Tags: java, plugins, macros, imagej

Hello I am trying to pass arguments to my ImageJ PlugIn. However it seems no matter what I pass, argument string will be considered as empty by the program. I couldn't find any documentation on the internet about THAT issue.

My Java plugIn looks like this, and compiles fine.

```
import ij.plugin.PlugIn;

public class Test implements PlugIn {
    public void run(String args) {

        IJ.log("Starting plugin Test");
        IJ.log("args: ." + args + ".");

    }
 }
```

I compile, make a .jar file and put it into the ImageJ plugins folder.
I can call it with the ImageJ userInterface (Plugin>Segmentation>Test) and the macro recorder will put the command used:

```
run("Test");
```

Then my code is executed, the log window pops-up as expected:

```
Starting plugin Test
args: ..
```

I can manually run the same command in a .ijm file, and get the same result.
However, when I run the following macro command:

```
run("Test", "my_string");
```

I get the same results in the log window:

```
Starting plugin Test
args: ..  //  <- I would like to get "my_string" passed there
```

Where it should have displayed (at least what I expect it to do)

```
Starting plugin Test
args: .my_string.
```

So my question is: how can I pass parameters to PlugIn and especially how to access them?
Many thanks

---

EDIT

---

Hey I found a way to bypass that:

Using the Macro.getOptions() : this method will retrieve the string passed in argument to the plugin. 
However, I still can't find a way to pass more than 1 string argument. I tried overloading the PlugIn.run() method but it doesn't work at all.

My quick fix is to put all my arguments in 1 string, and separating them by a space. Then I split this string:

```
String [] arguments = Macro.getOptions().split(" ");
```

I don't see a more convenient way to get around that. I can't believe how stupid this situation is.

Please, if you have a better solution, feel free to share! Thanks

Comment: Please try to understand the design of the software - which by the way has evolved since the 1990s - before complaining *"how stupid this situation is"*.

Comment: Sorry I did not mean to offense, I meant I couldn't believe the "hard way" was the only way of handling this issue. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing the `run(String arg)` method in [`ij.plugin.Plugin`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/plugin/PlugIn.html) with the ImageJ macro command [`run("command"\[, "options"\])`](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#run), which calls [`IJ.run(String command, String options)`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/ij/IJ.html#run%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

In the documentation for [`ij.plugin.Plugin#run(String arg)`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/ij/plugin/PlugIn.html#run%28java.lang.String%29), it says:

> This method is called when the plugin is loaded. 'arg', which may be blank, is the argument specified for this plugin in IJ_Props.txt.

So, `arg` is an optional argument that you can use in [`IJ_Props.txt`](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/download/IJ_Props.txt) or in the [`plugins.config`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/jar-demo.html) file of your plugin to assign different menu commands to different functions of your plugin (see also the [excellent documentation on the Fiji wiki](http://fiji.sc/Introduction_into_Developing_Plugins)).

To make use of the `options` parameter when running your plugin from macro code, you should use a [`GenericDialog`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/gui/GenericDialog.html) to get the options, or (as you apparently learned the hard way) use the helper function [`Macro.getOptions()`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/Macro.html).